# How to keep track of added items to make the final results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm building a function with the following header:

```
def sort_bydate(df, or_df, proportion1, proportion2, total_amount, username=None)
```

Where *df* is the Dataframe that contains the products in question that I want to get sorted, *or_df* is the original Dataframe with all the data, *total_amount* is the number of items to return, the proportions are just that, the proportion of items that fulfill the certain condition and *username* if it is indicated it checks the accesses the user has made to certain items.

Here is what this function does:

1. Takes **current date** and with that makes 3-time conditions:

   - Released last month (30 days before today)
   - Released last 3 months (120 to 30 days before today)
   - Data not included in 1 nor in 2
2. With those conditions **divides** the data (*df*) into three sub-dataframes:

   - *lastm*, with data released last month
   - *last3m*, with data released last three months
   - *left*, data left on the original data frame
3. Takes a random sample (`lastm = lastm['product'].sample(n = amount`) of each sub-dataframe, the amount depends on the proportion indicated and the total amount (i.e: if we indicate proportion1 = 0.4, proportion2 = 0.4 and total_amount = 5, it will take 2 prodcucts from the first subset, 2 products from the second subset and 1 of the third subset).
4. **Appends** each resulting subset to a final one that will be returned.

When a *username* is indicated, it checks its **accessed products** and makes the same division, 
what I am aiming to do is give preference to those accessed items (somehow) but I can't figure out an elegant way of doing it, it's all messy and ugly.

What I've been trying to do is the following:

1. Check the accessed products of the user in the original df (or_df).
2. Check which accessed products are on the list of products to sort (df).
3. If there are accessed products on the list, take a look at the number of products that we have, if there are total_amount or more (`accessed_products >= total_amount`) items just use that to make the sorting.
4. If the amount is not enough, a date checking has to be made (like in point 3).
5. Add each product to the resulting data frame (the one that will be returned) and change the number of items that have to be taken from the other subsets (this is what I don't know how to do).

I'm currently setting the amount like this:

```
    if results_lastm.size < proportion1*total_amount:
        amount_m = results_lastm.size
    else:
        amount_m = int(proportion1 * total_amount)
    if results_last3m.size < proportion2 * total_amount:
        amount_3m = results_last3m.size
    else:
        amount_3m = int((proportion1+proportion2)*total_amount - last_m_final.size)
    last_m_final = results_lastm['product'].sample(n = amount_m)
    last_3m_final = results_last3m['product'].sample(n = amount_3m) 
    rest_final = results_left['product'].sample(n = total_amount - last_m_final.size - last_3m_final.size) 
    return last_m_final.append(last_3m_final.append(rest_final))
```

How should I modify that to achieve my goal?

Comment: It would be clever to, maybe, just add a counter that keeps track of the already added products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did, in the end, is just **add** all of the accessed items to the final results if `amount of items < total amount`, and make the proportions exactly the same as before but **subtracting** the amount of added books from the total amount to make the new amounts for the rest of the items:

```
results.append(accesses['product'].head(accesses.shape[0]))
...
if username is not None:
    total_amount = total_amount - results.shape[0]
if results_lastm.size < proportion1*total_amount:
    amount_m = results_lastm.size
else:
    amount_m = int(proportion1 * total_amount)
if results_last3m.size < proportion2 * total_amount:
    amount_3m = results_last3m.size
else:
    amount_3m = int((proportion1+proportion2)*total_amount - amount_m)
```

I realized, that, in this case, it was more important to add the items without taking into account the date.